# Backing up all sharepoint web applications?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, backup

I have a sharepoint farm hooked to a named instance of SQL2008. 
I have a web application (it is also extended to another web app) that I would like to back up.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I am trying to back it up as I would like to create some custom changes. And if these changes cause any trouble I would like to get back to the backup.

Now, deos backing up a web application from Central Admin or Powershell backup everything sharepoint needs once I restore the web app back on at a later time??

Comment: I would try it on a development machine as if it will or not, it depends on your web application and custom solutions you had deployed I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you back up the site collection(s) through PowerShell it will pack all of the configuration and content and provide you a complete restore for that site collection if something were to go wrong.  I would focus on the site collection backup for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes!. Back up will ensure that all the Web application-related data and configurations are available for recovery, if something bad happens. I would suggest taking back up of both the web applications (original and extended)

Read this [article](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/sharepoint-2010-backup-and-recovery-configuring-backup) for more details:

You could do it via PowerShell

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod Full -Item <WebApplicationName> [-Verbose]
```